# Customer specific css based on subdomain with scss

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Anyone have any experience with customer specific css injection during runtime ?

We got a portal and want customers to be able to customise it. This would basically be 4 variables (colors, icon, background) but it affects about 100 css classes. We separated our scss so we got a base.scss part and specific branding-relevant classes in a branding.scss

We then use webpack to build all scss and create a `style.css` and a `vendor.style.css`. This would be extended by splitting the `style.css` into `style.scs` and `branding.css`. However this branding would be different for every customer and should be able to be changed by customers. They got sliders and color pickers etc in the portal.

I see two options how this could be done:

1. during each new build release, create a new customerABranding.css based on a brandingTemplate.scss and the customers chosen settings. Make that fetchable and injectable using Ajax, depending on the subdomain (e.g. customerA.company.com)
2. fetch the "not yet finished" css file that includes placeholders like $$CUSTOMER_BACKGROUND_URL$$ and do string.replace with the corresponding values  (seems sketchy). This custom css would have to be built every time during a new release and would require some hacky webpack file replace handling

both seems hacky, but I have no other ideas. Would really appreciate a discussion about this.

It feels like something that must have been done before but I can't seem to figure out an elegant way of doing it.